# autocomplete ignore by Edge 18 in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm using autocomplete="off" for inputtext in blazor  but its not working for Edge 18 version.
also trying autocomplete="anytext" but still its not working. both autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="anytext" are working fine for every browser.
Is there any other way to keep away autofill box from InputText?

Comment: Hi @Aditya patil, can you tell us the detailed Edge browser version? Based on your description, I have created a new Asp.net Core Blazor application and use the InputText component, then test it using Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQUfz.gif), as we can see that the `autocomplete="off"` attribute works well on Edge 18.18363 version. You can create a new application to check it, if still not working, can you share the relates code.

Comment: Thanks @ZhiLv , I'm using same Edge 18.18363  , I will try with new one

Answer (score 1):

On Edge 18 is only partially supported, read here : https://caniuse.com/?search=autocomplete

The only other possibility, I think, is to disable it from browser settings.